# Using composer with Magento2

Tags: magento2, php, composer

I installed Magento2 without composer. I would like to install a few extensions and another language but all tutorials I have seen use composer.

Is it possible to "add" composer when Magento is already installed ?
How do I have to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to install extensions with composer if Magento was not installed with composer. So you should start over with a fresh composer install.

Good news is, you can copy all the non-core files from `app` and then still use the same database, so nothing is lost.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Yes**, you can install it after Magento2 is installed.

1. First try before to check in console if you have a composer in your server like this:

   ```
   composer --help
   ```

   If command help displays, Composer is already installed else if you have an error message it means that it is not instaled
2. It's time to install it like this:

   ```
   curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
   mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
   ```

Nb: make sure that you're connected as **root**

[Magento DevDocs intall composer](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/integrator_install_composer.html)

Comment: I do have composer installed but the issue is since Magento was setup without composer I am missing the composer.json file etc.